# What should cellForRowAtIndexPath return if the table is empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I think if the table is empty, namely that

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[BNUtilitiesQuick getBizs] count];
}
```

always return 0

I would expect that `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` should not be called at all

This is important. I am making a program to search through things and sometimes after some searching, there is no result being returned.

However, is called anyway and I got an exception. What should I do?

Comment: Better put the crash logs here.

Comment: Check what is returned in `numberOfRowsInSection`, if it is 0, then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` may be called before the table view has realised it has zero rows and so shouldn't be called.

Therefore your implementation needs to check that the value of the row being passed in is not outside the bounds of your array. If it is, you need to return an empty cell (the documentation states returning `nil` will raise an exception).

Answer (score 1):

There is simply no way that `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called when the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method returns `0`. It is likely that the count is being returned incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

First print `[[BNUtilitiesQuick getBizs] count];`
 in `NSLog` and see if it really returns 0.

> If it shows 0, and if the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` still gets called, I suspect there is some ghost hanging around there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Often you would have a giant switch statement in a cellForRow... Meaning that you have to have a value to return in the default case. I usually return nil there.

This is required by the compiler to not show a warning, but it should never be actually called. This method is only called for row indexes that are possible due to what you reeturn in the numberOfSections and numberOdRowsInSection methods.

Answer (score 0):

What about returning 1 as count (or 10 for example), and that one cell will display dimmed text with "No Results" ?

(open your contacts app and search for something.. it will have about 10 rows , 9 are empty and 1 displays "no results")